# Delete Row Based on Variable Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have found another chain that lead me to deleting cells based on the static text that they contain, but now in addition I need to delete the dates in a similar fashion, but they are variable.

This is the code I am using for the static text removal:

```
'Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 6)
    If .value <> "ALLOW" _
        And .value <> "CHRG" _
        And .value <> "COST" _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

That works great, but when I run this report I run it for the previous 2 or 3 days (depending on the day of the week).  I need to delete anything that precedes two days before the earliest run date. For example: if I run the report on the 24th for the 22nd and 23rd, I want to delete anything dated earlier than the 20th.

I know it seems like the report could be run to do this, but trust me, it is as incapable of it as a T-Rex is of doing a back-flip.  I attempted to just alter the code for the static text, but with limited knowledge of VBA Code, I don't know if I am on the right track:

```
'Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.count, 5).End(x1Up).Row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 5)
    If .value < Today _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

Obviously, I don't have anything to account for the value of today's date minus the 4 days before the report is run, so I need help there as well.  In the current form I get an "application-defined or object-defined error" on the line:

```
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.count, 5).End(x1Up).Row To 2 Step -1
```

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Comment: `x1Up` is not the same as `xlUp` !

Comment: `If .value < (Today - 4) Then` will check the four days previous to the run date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited: InputBox added**

Use Date instead of Today.  EntireRow is not needed when Rows().Delete.

Sub M1()
    'Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim RowToTest As Long
    Dim DayCount As Long

```
DayCount = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How Days Back to CleanUp?", Default:=3, Type:=1)

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

    With Cells(RowToTest, 6)
        If .Value <> "ALLOW" _
           And .Value <> "CHRG" _
           And .Value <> "COST" _
           Then _
           Rows(RowToTest).Delete
    End With

Next RowToTest

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

    With Cells(RowToTest, 5)
        If .Value < (Date - DayCount) Then Rows(RowToTest).Delete
    End With

Next RowToTest
```

End Sub

Comment: @TKE-439 the way your are wrote your If statement is correct.  Your way is actually more efficient then my way.

Comment: That works perfectly now.  Let me ask this though; usually I run the report for the previous two days (on the 29th, I would run it for the 27th-28th).  For this, the cleanup macro works perfectly, but what if I have to run it a day late (run on the 30th for the 27th-28th).  In that case the

    If.Value < (Date - 3) Then Rows(RowsToTest).Delete

deletes days that are still needed since the calculation is based off of the current date.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TKE-439 I added an InputBox for you.